# Toastr Notifications in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, toastr

I'm using **Toastr** notification plugin in my `dotnetCore` razor application to display status messages. These notifications are working perfectly fine with all ajax calls and their responses (in javascript).

But I need to configure these responses on simple razor actions;

```
asp-action="ViewJobs" asp-controller="Job"
```

Like if there's some loading issue or rights issue, I need to show error messages as `toastr` notifications. I did some RnD on it and found out different solutions but nothing worked out for me.

I've tried [MVC wrapper for Toastr](http://labs.bjfocus.co.uk/2014/06/create-an-mvc-wrapper-for-toastr/) that handles all kind of toastrs in controller but its specific for MVC and trying to add some files in `App_Code` that is not available in `dotnetcore` and furthermore its having `@helper` tag that is no more supported in `dotnetcore`. `(Tell me if there's any other workaround to use this solution?)`

Then I tried this solution [NToastNotify](https://nabinked.com/2017/01/26/toast-notificationin-asp-net-core-mvc/) , but got stuck again, because it needs `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (>= 1.1.2)` while I'm using `version 1.0.0` and I cannot update my version because then I need to update so many files in my project.

So Is there any other solution to handle this situation?? Can't I fulfill my requirement with simple viewbag or tempdata ??

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone who is stuck like me and in search of solution, I ended up using [NToastNotify](https://github.com/nabinked/ntoastnotify/) library after updating my packages to its required versions and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can show toast notification with simple ViewBag. Here is my code.

The following code will display a toast error while loading the page, data from ViewBag

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var title = '@ViewBag.Title';
            var message = '@ViewBag.Message';
            toastr.error(message, title);
        });
    </script>
}
```

And you can write similar code when user clicks on a button and want to show toast notifications.

```
$("#ToastNotification").click(function(){
    var title = '@ViewBag.Title';
    var message = '@ViewBag.Message';
    toastr.info(message, title);
});
```

I have added the toast script and css in the layout page

Comment: But if i have 5,6 buttons on a page, I've to handle each click??